# Connect a VTK callback with a Qt slot

Tags: callback, qt4, signals-slots, vtk, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to connect a `VTK`callback to a `Qt` slot, so the slot will be fired when the callback happens.

I'm using a `QVTKWidget` to render a point cloud that has been added into a `PCLVisualizer` (from the point cloud library, PCL).

Let's show  some code:

**PointCloud.h**

```
class PointCloud: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
  private:
    static void loadStartCallback(
      vtkObject *caller,
      unsigned long eventId,
      void *clientData,
      void *callData
    );

    static void loadEndCallback(
      vtkObject *caller,
      unsigned long eventId,
      void *clientData,
      void *callData
    );
    void load(void);
    // more funcs and methods

  private:
   QVTKWidget* widget;
   pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer* visualizer;
   unsinged long observerStartTag;
   unsinged long observerEndTag;
   // more attributes
}
```

**PointCloud.cpp**

```
  void PointCloud::loadStartCallback(
    vtkObject* caller,
    unsigned long eventId,
    void* clientData,
    void* callData
  ) {
    qDebug() << "\t\tPointCloud - loadCallback started\n";
    if(clientData) {
      PointCloud* self = reinterpret_cast<PointCloud*>( clientData );
      self->widget->GetRenderWindow()->RemoveObserver(self->observerStartTag);
  }

  void PointCloud::loadEndCallback(
    vtkObject* caller,
    unsigned long eventId,
    void* clientData,
    void* callData
  ) {
    qDebug() << "\t\tPointCloud - loadCallback ended\n";
    if(clientData) {
      PointCloud* self = reinterpret_cast<PointCloud*>( clientData );
      self->widget->GetRenderWindow()->RemoveObserver(self->observerEndTag);
    }
  }

 void load(void) {
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = visualizer->getRenderWindow();

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkCallbackCommand> startCallback = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCallbackCommand>::New();
    startCallback->SetCallback( loadStartCallback );
    startCallback->SetClientData(this);
    observerStartTag = renderWindow->AddObserver(vtkCommand::StartEvent, startCallback );

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCallbackCommand> endCallback = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCallbackCommand>::New();
    endCallback->SetCallback( loadEndCallback );
    endCallback->SetClientData(this);
    observerEndTag = renderWindow->AddObserver(vtkCommand::EndEvent, endCallback );

    // more processing. local_cloud is already populated 
    // and functional at this point
    widget->SetRenderWindow( renderWindow );
    visualizer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(local_cloud, "local_cloud");
    widget->Show();
    widget->Update();
 }
```

This works well, once the cloud rendering starts, the *PointCloud - loadCallback started* is printed and when the rendering has ended and the cloud is shown, the message *PointCloud - loadCallback ended* is printed.

Now, besides printing the end message, I want to fire a `Qt` slot as well. I'm trying to use the `vtkEventQtSlotConnect` class for that, as it seems that is the right choice for connecting callbacks to slots:

**New in PointCloud.h**

```
private slots:
  void test(void);
```

**New in PointCloud.cpp**

```
void PointCloud::test(void) { qDebug() << "\t\tThis is a test\n; }
```

**Added into PointCloud::load(), before calling visualizer->addPointCloud**

```
    vtkEventQtSlotConnect* vtk_qt_connector = vtkEventQtSlotConnect::New();
    vtk_qt_connector->Connect(
        renderWindow,
        vtkCommand::EndEvent,
        this,
        SLOT(test(void)),
        0,
        1.0
    );

    // AFTER widget->Update()
    vtk_qt_connector->Disconnect(); // NO PARAM: disconnects ALL slots
    vtk_qt_connector->Delete();
  } // End of PointCloud::load()
```

With those additions, the messages in the callbacks are printed, but the message inside the `test()` slot is never shown.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

In the `VTK`examples for callbacks that I've seen, a `vtkRendeWindowInteractor` is used to manage the callbacks. However, If I add the callback observer to it, it is not as accurate as adding them to the render window directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,
I have checked again the code and found something new. Some co-worker has added a `QThread` in the `load()` method to smooth things, but forgot to document/tell that there was a `QThread`there.

**In PointCloud::load()**

```
 QThread* thread = new QThread;
 ThreadedCloud* tcloud = new ThreadedCloud; // computes internal vars and more
 tcloud->moveToThread(thread);

 connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), tcloud, SLOT(read()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
 connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
 connect(tcloud, SIGNAL(cloudIsLoaded()), this, SLOT(addCloudToViewer()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
 connect(tcloud, SIGNAL(cloudIsLoaded()), thread, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
 connect(tcloud, SIGNAL(cloudIsLoaded()), tcloud, SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
 connect(tcloud, SIGNAL(cloudIsNotLoaded(std::string)), this, SLOT(errorLoadingCloud(std::string)), Qt::QueuedConnection );
 thread->start();
```

The `cloudIsLoaded()` is a signal that is emitted when the thread has finished whatever it has to do and we're ready to add the cloud to the `PCLVisualizer` and render it. That is done in `addCloudToViewer`.

The key factor here is that once the thread is started, the control flow exits the `load()`method and because I'm disconnecting the callback/slot before the end of the method, once the cloud is being rendererd that connection isn't there anymore!

So the solution was to move the `vtk_qt_connector` inside the `addCloudToViewer` method and do there the callback/slot connection.